# Jquery and PHP update mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to update a database entry through jQuery and AJAX.
I am checking that the values i send over is correct - but I am not sure how to check why the database is not updated.

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".approve", function(){
    var classes = $(this).parents('div:eq(0)'); // this gets the parent classes.
    i = 0;
    var pros = [];
    classes.find(".prosncons .pros ul li").each(function(){
        pros.push($(this).text());
    });
    var cons = [];
    classes.find(".prosncons .cons ul li").each(function(){
        cons.push($(this).text());
    });
    var notes = classes.find(".notes").text();
    var id = classes.find(".id").text();
    var data = "method=approve&pros="+pros+"&cons="+cons+"&notes="+notes+"&id="+id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../scripts/upload.php",
      data: data,
      success: $(this).closest(".approval").remove(),
    });
});
```

PHP::

```
if($method == "approve"){
        $sql = "UPDATE `approval` SET approved = 1 WHERE pros=:pros, cons=:cons, notes=:notes, id=:id";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array(':pros' => $pros, ':cons' => $cons, ':notes' => $notes, ':id'=> $id));
    }
```

Comment: You're not checking the result of `$statement->execute(...)` is it working?

Comment: Also, you are setting up those variables from the `$_POST` array are you?  They do not exist automatically as separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are t sending in the right way your data to the php file

Change your ajax request with this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../scripts/upload.php",
      data: { method: "approve", pros: pros, cons:cons, note:notes, id:id },
      success: $(this).closest(".approval").remove(),
    });
```

To get your variable into the php file you can retireve that with `$_POST['var_name']`
In your php try this to check `method`:

```
if($_POST['method'] == "approve"){
        $sql = "UPDATE `approval` SET approved = 1 WHERE pros=:pros, cons=:cons, notes=:notes, id=:id";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array(':pros' => $_POST['pros'], ':cons' => $_POST['cons'], ':notes' => $_POST['notes'], ':id'=> $_POST['id']));
    }
```

Comment: If the problem is the lack of variable initialisation, (with regard to your `$_POST` usage), then the other variables probably need that too.

Comment: I have the variable initialized further up my PHP script ^^ But thanks for the AJAX help :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does still not work - My best guess would be the php update string? Do i need it to be AND or "," in between the WHERE conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `$conn->error` for the last error. This should tell you if you have an error.

I would normally check if there is an error and if there is I would return a status of error so my JS code knows there was a problem, then handle it.

Comment: Well I can't really do that - as I am sending the info via jQuery I am never really seeing the page where this would be output.

Comment: You can see the response page via the Chrome Dev Tools or the Firebug in FF. And in your success: you can check for errors. success: function(result) { if(result === 'error') { /*do something*/} else {/*do the remove*/} }.  You get the picture.